# VB.NET Get Value on Click from List Box

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

I have list of attachments with Names from SQL Table where when I select a file it download it from the Server. What I need to Select the name and get the File name (Value Feild)
I was able to run it smoothly but when I select from the List it gives me the Original File name.
There is the Code:

```
   Protected Sub listload()
    key = CardView.GetCardValues(CardView.FocusedCardIndex, CardView.KeyFieldName)
    Dim sql As String = String.Format("Select Name,[File] from tblFile where ParentType='Contract' and ParentID = '{0}' order by ID", key)
    Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ProjectC").ConnectionString)
    Dim SelectCommand As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
    conn.Open()
    attlist.Items.Clear()
    Dim Reader As SqlDataReader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader()
    While Reader.Read()
        If Reader.HasRows Then
            attlist.Items.Add(Reader("Name").ToString)
            attlist.ValueField = Reader("File").ToString
        End If
    End While
    conn.Close()
    conn.Dispose()
End Sub

Protected Sub attlist_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles attlist.SelectedIndexChanged
    Response.ContentType = "APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM"
    Dim Header As [String] = "Attachment; Filename=" + attlist.SelectedItem.Value
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", Header)
    Dim Dfile As New System.IO.FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Files/Attachments/" + attlist.SelectedItem.Value))
    Response.WriteFile(Dfile.FullName)
    Response.[End]()
End Sub
```

Column [Name] is the Displayed name and Column [File] is the attachment
Appreciate your help 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add objects of type ListItem to fill the Text and Value properties. The correct code would be:

```
 While Reader.Read()
    If Reader.HasRows Then
        attlist.Items.Add(new ListItem(Reader("Name").ToString(),Reader("File").ToString()))
    End If
End While
```